# Bootstrap grid system on small div does not work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

If I choose small width (lower then 360)  on bootstrap container (set wrapping container width to 359px) row breaks, am I doing something wrong or is it bootstrap bug ?

Code example:

`<div style="width: 360px;" class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 50px;">
        <div class="col-xs-1" style="background: red"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" style="background: green"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-9" style="background: orange"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" style="background: yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbOWGW

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you specified fixed width of the container (360px) and when the screen is smaller than 360px, your container has still 360px width.

You can use CSS something like this:

```
.container {
  width: 360px;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

or (mobile first approach):

```
@media (min-width: 360px) {
  .container {
    width: 360px;
  }
}
```

In the second option you have to get rid of your inline style `width: 360px` in your HTML code

### [CODEPEN 1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVdKxY)

### [CODEPEN 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGYjwb)